# Faceting geom_tile in ggplot2 with different axis scales produces a banded image

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, geom-tile

I'm having some unexpected behavior in ggplot with `geom_tile()` and `facet`ing.

Here's the classic "volcano" tile:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
volcano %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value))
```

[image]

Good.  Now let's add an index column and `facet` the image...

```
volcano %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  cross_join(tibble(idx = c(1,2,3))) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
    facet_wrap(vars(idx))
```

[image]

OK.  That's nice.  Now I'm going to create different scales on the x axis and use the `scales = "free"` parameter...

```
volcano %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  cross_join(tibble(idx = c(1,2,3))) %>%
  mutate(Var1 = Var1/idx) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(idx), scales = "free")
}
```

[image]

Note the x-axis values differ between the last graph and this one.

It's not that `ggplot` has a fundamental problem with the re-scaled axis.  Here I plot the third panel of the prior image by itself with no `facet`ing.

```
volcano %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  cross_join(tibble(idx = c(1,2,3))) %>%
  mutate(Var1 = Var1/idx) %>%
  filter(idx == 3) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value))
```

[image]

The problem is `facet`ing with different scales.  The problem persists even if I don't use `scales = "free"` parameter...

```
volcano %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  cross_join(tibble(idx = c(1,2,3))) %>%
  mutate(Var1 = Var1/idx) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(idx))
```

[image]

Seems lake a bug to me, but I don't see an issue report when I search "geom_tile facet" on github tidyverse/ggplot.

Anyone out there have an idea how I could get a proper plot without the banding?

UPDATE: Here is a small example that shows what is going on in more detail.  `ggplot` appears to be calculating the width of each column in the tile using one scale, and applying that width to all of the plots...

```
# make some data
data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rep(1:10, each=10), value = runif(100)) %>%

  # duplicate the data and alter the scale of the second set
  bind_rows(., mutate(., x=x/3), .id = "idx") %>%

  # plot with faceting
  ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill = value)) + facet_wrap("idx")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could vary tile width by facet. ggplot2 tiles are based on what ggplot2 identifies as the "resolution" of the data.

```
volcano %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  cross_join(tibble(idx = c(1,2,3))) %>%
  mutate(width = max(diff(Var1), na.rm = TRUE), .by = idx) |>
   ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value, width = width)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(idx), scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Seems odd to me, but is at least consistent. Even not using `facet`ing, `geom_tile` will take the minimum spacing between adjacent x or y axis values as the width and height of the tiles (pixels).  This behavior can result in a plot of showing an array of disconnected individual tiles.  For example: `volcano |> reshape2::melt() |> mutate(Var1 = log(Var1), Var2 = log(Var2)) |> ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value))`  Building on Jon's solution, this can be resolved by setting a custom `width`for each row and custom `height` for each column.